# Facing Error: while hosting website on GitHub after creating repository

Tags: node.js, runtime-error, pug, node-modules, github-pages

This is my GitHub repository for Dance Website I created using Pug, CSS, NodeJs
[This is my GitHub repository for Dance Website I created using Pug, CSS, NodeJs](https://github.com/BIRBAHADUR07/Dance_Website)

I don't know how to host this site after uploading all files on GitHub.

This is how my site looks when running at localhost:8000
[This is how my site looks when running at localhost:8000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHprU.png)

This is the error GitHub Shows me
[This is the error GitHub Shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR5rA.png)

Answer (score 1):

I see your web app is built with Express. This means you would need a server to run it.

From what I understand, [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/) can only be used to host a static websites (HTML, CSS and JS files for the front end).

In your case, since have server code involved, you may look at Heroku, AWS, Azure or GCP (among others) to host your website.